# Server closes connection unexpectedly when connecting to Azure Postgres

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connect to Azure Postgresql using psql from my local machine and get the following error:

```sh
$ psql "host=username.postgres.database.azure.com port=5432 dbname=postgres user=username@domain password=mypassword sslmode=require"
psql: error: could not connect to server: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

Local Postgres version: 12.1, Azure Postgres database version: 10, macOS Majove.

This issue only recently started after I reinstalled Postgres using Homebrew.  I have no issues running `$ psql --host=localhost`.

I've tried installing `postgresql@10` with homebrew so that when I run `psql` I get the message `psql (12.1, server 10.11)`.  But when I attempt to log into Azure Postgres I get the same error as above.

I'm fairly new to Postgres and Azure and would appreciate any suggestions.

**Update:**

Thanks for the comments and feedback.

I properly installed Postgres 10 with Homebrew and linked it to fix the problem.

```sh
$ brew services stop postgresql
$ brew install postgresql@10
$ brew services start postgresql@10
$ brew link --overwrite --force postgresql@10
```

I can now access the Azure database as expected.

Comment: have you tried a retry logic?

Comment: Try to install the PostgreSQL Client for macOS with Homebrew referring to [this](https://www.compose.com/articles/postgresql-tips-installing-the-postgresql-client/) again?

Comment: I encounter the same issue that you have right now. I can connect to the database using GUI client but not psql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, you could install the PostgreSQL Client for macOS with Homebrew properly then link it as it will symlink all the tools into the `/usr/local/bin` directory.

To fix this issue, run the following commands:

```
$ brew services stop postgresql
$ brew install postgresql@10
$ brew services start postgresql@10
$ brew link --overwrite --force postgresql@10
```

Ref: https://www.compose.com/articles/postgresql-tips-installing-the-postgresql-client/