# "psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly" working locally on MacOS

Tags: postgresql, macos

I encountered a weird issue with my Postgres, **suddenly** (after YEARS) I can't connect to it using my Golang application code or via `psql` but the funny thing is that my DBeaver application can!

This is what I try and the error I get:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost                                                                                               
psql: server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
```

I did some research and tried a bunch of stuff which seems to resolve this issue for other users :

1. Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934364/psql-server-closed-the-connection-unexepectedly) I made sure that both `pg_hba.conf` and `postgresql.conf` files configured correctly (added `listen_addresses = '*'` to `postgresql.conf` and made sure that I accept any IP `host  all  all  0.0.0.0/0  trust` in `pg_hba.conf`.
2. Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59548242/server-closes-connection-unexpectedly-when-connecting-to-azure-postgres) I've downgraded my Postgres version from 12 to 10 and it did not work either.
3. Removed EVERYTHING related to Postgres and reinstalled using Homebrew using this [guide](https://gist.github.com/ibraheem4/ce5ccd3e4d7a65589ce84f2a3b7c23a3)
4. Removed the Homebrew installation and tried to use the [PostgresApp for Mac](https://postgresapp.com/) - no luck either.

I'm stuck! 
Does anyone know what could go wrong? I have no idea what went wrong to cause this issue.
I'm working on OSX Catalina 10.15.4 if it helps.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

**Update:**

Step 2 works great, the issue was with the latest update of my anti-virus (ESET).

Comment: What do you see in the database logs when you try to connect?

Comment: Using step #2 I've investigated the server log and saw that the server is accepting connections on ```127.0.0.1``` and using this it worked, this is so weird. I used to work using ```localhost``` all the time. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Found out that the actual issue was with the latest update of my anti-virus (ESET), disabling the Firewall resolved the issue.