# azure + postgresql: How to fix error: Unable to connect to server: server closed the connection unexpectedly

Tags: postgresql, azure, psql, pgadmin-4, azure-postgresql

i use postgresql server in azure. Until few hours ago I was able to access the server from pgAdmin 4 but now I get the following error:

' Unable to connect to server:
server closed the connection unexpectedly
This probably means the server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request. '

Same for using psql.

From my node js backend app I can access the database to get and edit the db.

How can I fix the access for the db server from pgAdmin 4 and psql?

EDIT:
I managed to connect from psql but still not from pgAdmin 4, and after enabling disconnection logs in azure I get this log:
' An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59640480/798053 fixed it for me:

```
$ brew services stop postgresql
$ brew install postgresql@10
$ brew services start postgresql@10
$ brew link --overwrite --force postgresql@10ode here
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your IP address or VNet in Connection Security. By default it is blocked.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had chosen to create an Azure SQL Database rather than an Azure Database for PostgreSQL. I doubt many others have made this mistake, but if you have, it will cause this error!